# Silverlight Control like C# Text Editor in VS

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I builded a mechanizm which is responsible for creating scripts based on C# language.
To do that I used TextEdit where I paste C# code and CodeDom mechanizm to generate dynamic type on server side.

Everything is working great.

I want to replace this TextEdit. I need component who will give me an oportunity to write C# code with right formatting (as in Visual Studio Text Editor) and would be great if this component will be validate it's content (C# syntax).

Has anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: [Scintilla.NET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=218934)

Answer (score 0):

check this: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/SyntaxHighlighting.aspx